# Tablet does not connect to the hotspot

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

My Samsung tablet was working just fine. Now it does not connect to the Internet via our hotspot. It does not even scan and see the available connections. When I try to turn WiFi on, it turns ON momentarily and then again turns back OFF saying **To see available networks, turn on wi-fi**

Comment: What kind of hotspot are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score -2):

This happened to me once and I just made a factory reset. However this did not work for a friend.